# makefile: want to test if any file exists (*.sh)

Tags: makefile

In a makefile I want to check if there are any .sh files and chmod them if any.

```
test -f !/usr/local/bin/myapp/*.sh || chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/myapp/*.sh
```

This is the output:

```
chmod: cannot access '/usr/local/bin/myapp/*.sh': No such file or directory
makefile:102: recipe for target 'install' failed
make: *** [install] Error 1
```

I don't like using `chmod -f` as I might miss other errors

Is there a way to handle this?

Comment: `for i in /usr/local/bin/myapp/*.sh; do chmod 755 "$$i"; done`?

Comment: @melpomene same error `chmod: cannot access '/usr/local/bin/myapp/*.sh': No such file or directory` (do you need 2 $ in `"$$i"` ?)

Comment: Why aren't those shell script marked executable in the first place?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error; the command in the question works in my makefile. (GNUMake 3.81)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is GNU `find`:

```
find /usr/local/bin/myapp/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.sh" -exec chmod 755 {} +
```